# Java - Why doesn't method display?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
   {
      double apples = 1.7;
      //showSum(5, 10);

   }


   public static void apples(double fruit)
   {

      System.out.println("number of fruit: " + fruit);
   }
}
```

I don't know why this isn't displaying fruit in the method apples.
I had another portion of the code to display `showSum` and that worked just fine. So i'm not sure why it won't display fruit. I wanted to cast it as an *int* from a *double*

Comment: Did you call `apples(1.7);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a value to `apples`.
I think you are confused that apples is a variable and also declared as a method. It would be better to rename the method to something more generic like `printFruit` and call the method. See the code below:

```
import java.io.*;

public class test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
   {
      double apples = 1.7;
      printFruit(apples);
      //showSum(5, 10);

   }


   public static void printFruit(double fruit)
   {

     System.out.println("number of fruit: " + fruit);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call apples method same as you are calling showSum i.e is apples(1.7).
"double apples = 1.7;" is creating a variable with name apple and assigning it value 1.7